# FreeImage_Load Memory Leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, textures, freeimage

Valgrind is giving me a report of some memory leaks from a texture loading method I have. I have traced it back to one method, but it seems to be a leak in the FreeImage library itself?

(The rest of the memory leaks are all from FreeImage_Load too, omitted here)

```
==4295== 4,320,746 (8 direct, 4,320,738 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 210 of 210
==4295==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4295==    by 0x85148C: FreeImage_AllocateHeaderT (in /tmp/lab)
==4295==    by 0x851913: FreeImage_AllocateHeader (in /tmp/lab)
==4295==    by 0x8698AE: Load(FreeImageIO*, void*, int, int, void*) (in /tmp/lab)
==4295==    by 0x855B44: FreeImage_LoadFromHandle (in /tmp/lab)
==4295==    by 0x855BE0: FreeImage_Load (in /tmp/lab)
==4295==    by 0x41433F: Texture::LoadTexture(std::string, float, float) (Texture.cpp:7)
==4295==    by 0x417E2B: World::LoadTextures() (World.cpp:27)
==4295==    by 0x4119E5: main (project_main.cpp:217)
==4295== 
==4295== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4295==    definitely lost: 12,328 bytes in 17 blocks
==4295==    indirectly lost: 15,095,237 bytes in 554 blocks
==4295==      possibly lost: 845,677 bytes in 93 blocks
==4295==    still reachable: 47,631 bytes in 425 blocks
==4295==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

This seems to indicate that the leak is in the Texture::LoadTexture method, here is that method:

```
GLuint Texture::LoadTexture(std::string filename, float width, float height){   

    //Load Image
    FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT format = FreeImage_GetFileType(filename.c_str(), 0);      
    FIBITMAP *image = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(FreeImage_Load(format, filename.c_str()));
    BYTE *bits = FreeImage_GetBits(image);

    //Get width, height, bitnumber
    int w = FreeImage_GetWidth(image);
    int h = FreeImage_GetHeight(image);
    int nBPP =  FreeImage_GetBPP(image);

    std::cout<<filename<<" "<<w<<"*"<<h<< " " << nBPP << std::endl;

    //Generate texture references
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    //Bind
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    //Set parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);       
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); 

    //Generate actual texture from image data (mipmaps)
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, w, h, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bits); 

    //Unload image
    FreeImage_Unload(image);            

    //Add texture info to a map
    textures.insert(std::pair<GLuint, TextureInfo>(textureID, TextureInfo(textureID, w, h, nBPP)));     

    if (glGetError()) {
        std::cout << "There was an error loading the texture" << std::endl;
    }   

    //Return OpenGL textureID
    return textureID;
}
```

Any help anyone can give appreciated, not sure how to go about debugging this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a problem with this line:

```
FIBITMAP *image = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(FreeImage_Load(format, filename.c_str()));
```

The `FreeImage_Load()` call returns a `FIBITMAP *` that you must release by calling `FreeImage_Unload()`. In your code you treat the returned pointer as a temporary value and pass it to `FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits()` but you don't save it anywhere. You leak memory because you lose the pointer and can no longer release the resource.

Note that `FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits()` makes a *clone* of the bitmap so you must call `FreeImage_Unload()` to release it in addition to the original `FIBITMAP *`.