# Memory leak while converting images with FreeImage.Net

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, freeimage

When loading the image with the nuget package, (FreeImage 3.18.0.0) it does not unload memory even if '''dib.SetNull()''' was set.

```
var dib = FreeImage.Load(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_PNG, pngFile.FullName,
FREE_IMAGE_LOAD_FLAGS.DEFAULT);
FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JP2, dib, jpgFile.FullName, FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.JPEG_OPTIMIZE);
dib.SetNull();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FreeImage](https://freeimage.sourceforge.io/fnet/html/520DD347.htm) has additional copy of image you need to unload.
[FreeImage_Load Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742092/freeimage-load-memory-leak)

try:
**FreeImage.Unload(dib);**

```
var dib = FreeImage.Load(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_PNG, pngFile.FullName,
FREE_IMAGE_LOAD_FLAGS.DEFAULT);
FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JP2, dib, jpgFile.FullName, FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.JPEG_OPTIMIZE);
FreeImage.Unload(dib);
dib.SetNull();
```

Comment: While memory was increased over the time up to crashing computer system, now all is working perfect without memory leak anymore. Thank you.

Comment: I would put it in a `try/finally` to guarantee unload